# Combining multiple contingency tables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, fishers-exact-test, cochran-q

I have images that are evaluated by different experts. Basically, each expert look at the same pictures and saying whether a feature in the image exists or not. We have some images from diseased and normal people. The idea is to find whether a particular feature of the image is associated with disease. IF there were only a single expert we would be able to do a Fisher’s exact test. But there are multiple experts so we need a way to combine multiple contingency tables to get a single p value. By digging internet, I found that “Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel statistics” does something similar to this. However, I still have questions whether this is the appropriate test. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do all the experts evaluate all the images?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simplify this if you stop thinking of it as a collection of contingency tables, and re-envisage it as a simple linear model (with binomial response ie logistic regression).

- The *response* variable is whether the image is actually from someone with a disease (I presume you have this information, and also that the experts did not know this in advance, as otherwise the whole exercise seems a bit pointless).
- The *explanatory* variable is how many experts (or perhaps what proportion of experts) rated the image as having the feature you're interested in.  If there are actually multiple features, you can have as many of these explanatory variables (and indeed interactions) as you want.

Then you can just fit this as a logistic regression model, or possibly as a generalized additive model with a binomial response if you want to allow for non-linearity between the "proportion of experts who saw the feature" and the response.

Alternatively (but same basic idea), you could use a similar approach but make the "number of experts who saw the feature" an ordered categorical explanatory variable.  This would make sense if you think (for example) there is a radical discontinuity between 0, 1 or 2 experts who see the feature rather than a smooth progression of "the more who see it, the more likely it is to be there.".

Comment: Thats a good idea, I will definitely try this if i am able to get the appropriate data. However, I think I only have the contingency tables and it might take a while to get the actual assesment on the image level so my first go is a contingency table approach. So I want to ask whether there is at least statistically something wrong with the contingency table approach and the CMH test?

Comment: I don't know the CMH test so can't help on that.  But do you mean (by "actual assessment on the image level") that you don't know which images actually were associated with disease?  If so I don't think you can solve your problem by any means.

Comment: Thanks Peter, the person that collected the data unfortunately only have the contingency tables not the actual assesment the experts  made. I can not calculate for a given image how many experts rated it as existent or non existent.

Comment: I'm really unclear what is in the contingency tables.  If you don't have information on how many experts rated it as existent or non existent, what actually do you have?